# Why does this code produce the same output for both method calls?

Tags: c#, static

Why does this code produce the same output for both method calls? I would have assumed that because one method is a normal public method and is called from an instance then it would generate a different random number to the static method call as the instance is seperate from the one created for the static method call?

```
class ClassWithStaticMembers
{

    public static int ReturnAnIntStatic()
    {
        Random random = new Random();
        return random.Next();
    }

    public int ReturnAnInt()
    {
        Random random = new Random();
        return random.Next();
    }
}

class Program
{

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        ClassWithStaticMembers classWithStaticMembers = new ClassWithStaticMembers();

        //We can do this because the method is declared static. 
        Console.WriteLine(ClassWithStaticMembers.ReturnAnIntStatic());

        //This can be used as we have not declared this method static
        Console.WriteLine(classWithStaticMembers.ReturnAnInt());

        Console.ReadKey();

}
```

}

Output is as follows:

12055544
12055544

Can someone explain why using a method call from an instance of a class procuces the same result as a method call from a static method? Are the instances generated for the method calls not different?

EDIT: Further to this. Is the instance of ClassWithStaticMembers used to call the public method seperate to the static call. By which I mean would the compiler use the same instance again if it recognises I am making a call to the same class later in the file?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

That's because the [Random](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.random.aspx) is by default seeded by the current ticks and since both methods are called at almost the same time, they will produce the same numbers. This is explained in the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h343ddh9.aspx):

> The default seed value is derived from the system clock and has finite
>   resolution. As a result, different Random objects that are created in
>   close succession by a call to the default constructor will have
>   identical default seed values and, therefore, will produce identical
>   sets of random numbers. This problem can be avoided by using a single
>   Random object to generate all random numbers. You can also work around
>   it by modifying the seed value returned by the system clock and then
>   explicitly providing this new seed value to the Random(Int32)
>   constructor. For more information, see the Random(Int32) constructor.

Put a sleep between the 2 method calls to observe the difference:

```
Console.WriteLine(ClassWithStaticMembers.ReturnAnIntStatic());
Thread.Sleep(2000);
Console.WriteLine(classWithStaticMembers.ReturnAnInt());
```

Or use a different constructor for the Random class to seed them differently. Or simply use the same static instance of a `Random` class:

```
class ClassWithStaticMembers
{
    private static Random random = new Random();

    public static int ReturnAnIntStatic()
    {
        return random.Next();
    }

    public int ReturnAnInt()
    {
        return random.Next();
    }
}

class Program
{

    static void Main()
    {
        var classWithStaticMembers = new ClassWithStaticMembers();
        Console.WriteLine(ClassWithStaticMembers.ReturnAnIntStatic());
        Console.WriteLine(classWithStaticMembers.ReturnAnInt());
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

That's the reason why you should never use the Random class when you require real randomness and not pseudo random numbers. For example in cryptography you should use the [RNGCryptoServiceProvider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.rngcryptoserviceprovider.aspx) instead of the `Random` class. Once you know the initial seed value that was used to instantiate the Random class, you can predict all the numbers this class is going to generate.

Comment: Thanks for the clear answer. Makes total sense now. Please see my further comment on the OP as I could do with something else clearing up.

Comment: @CSharpened, in order to invoke an instance method you need an instance of a class. And when you are calling a static method you are not using any instance at all.

Comment: If you have not got any instance at all how does the compiler know where the code is? Is this where the special part of the heap comes in? Is the static method stored there ready for use?

Comment: @CSharpened, since a static class is never instantiated there's no reference to it. Its methods are just functions loaded into memory when the CLR loads the assembly. They are stored no what is called a Loader Heap. I would recommend you the following article to better understand the internals of how the CLR creates runtime objects: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163791.aspx But we are getting a little off-topic here with your initial question which was about the Random class and the reason why it was generating the same values. Nothing to do with instance or static classes.

Answer (score 4):

A guess: It is probably because of the use of the Random Number Generator. Often times, if you initialize a Generator (in any language), it uses the current time as a seed. In your case, this happens at about the same time, so the Generator will return the same number.

In other words: what happens if you do a Console.WriteLine() instead? (or rather return a const int)

EDIT: happens AT the same time, not about, the number of ticks is the same.

Comment: I see so it is not a case of it being the instances being the same but rather a coincidence of time used by the random generator that causes this? I wasnt sure if it was the static instance being reused by the compiler to run the call to the public method.

Comment: The documentation even warns of such situations: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h343ddh9.aspx Random Number Generators have to be seeded, and it looks like C# uses a fairly low resolution time source as the (default) seed. Probably just using the time in seconds!

Comment: exactly, just return 5 in one method and 7 in the other, or do the sleep suggested by Darin.

Comment: @Kitsune: From memory, I think the resolution is about 15ms. Much smaller than a second, but obviously a lot can happen in that 15ms stretch on a modern machine.

Comment: @LukeH Ah, a bit better, but 15ms is still pretty massive from the point of view of the computer! 15ms is as long as about *three* time slices on Windows!

Answer (score 4):

This has nothing to do with the distinction between static and instance members.

You're instantiating a `Random` instance inside each method, and because the methods are called in quick succession both `Random` instances will use the same seed and therefore produce the same output.

You could use a simpler example to demonstrate that the static and instance methods are distinct:

```
class ClassWithStaticMembers
{
    public static int ReturnAnIntStatic()
    {
        return 123;
    }

    public int ReturnAnInt()
    {
        return 42;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Because in both cases you're using an **instance** of the `Random` class; which, due to the fact that they will both be instantiated at very very similar times, produce the same output.

If you use your original code, but introduce a wait between the 2 method calls, it produces different numbers, as per this live example: http://rextester.com/UNH72532

The correct way to use the `Random` class is to have 1 static instance of it

```
class ClassWithStaticMembers
{
    private static Random rnd = new Random();
    public static int ReturnAnIntStatic()
    {
        return rnd.Next();
    }
    public int ReturnAnInt()
    {
        return rnd.Next();
    }
}
```

Both these methods will now produce a random number, check this live example based on your code: http://rextester.com/NBND87340